# mvc4 How to extract value from a tolist query in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

Ok so this is the basic setup; A user logins I get the unique ID of that user  **myid**, I then try to get a list of that logged in user friends by going into the friends table which is shown in the variable **myfriends** notice that I have only selected the friendID column which represents the uniqueID of a friend. I then compare the myid to the profileID which should match if they're friends. The problem is that I am using a .**tolist()** on the **myfriends** variable and I can't seem to extract the friendID (I am using the tolist() because a user can have more than 1 friend but the tolist only counts the amount of records) to compare in the **friendprofile** variable because the .tolist() only gives a value of how many records are extracted. How can I get the friendID value from myfriends so that I can compare it in the friendprofile so that I can show the users friends profile ? any help would be great

```
       [Authorize]
        public ActionResult myprofile()
    {
// Logged in User unique ID                     
int myid = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
 // list of Logged in User friends by ID
                    var myfriends = sqlConnection.Query<friend>("Select friendID from friends where myid=@profileID",new { profileID = myid }).ToList();
                    // get friends profiles
                    var friendprofile = sqlConnection.Query<profile>("Select * from profiles where friendID=@profile",new { profile = myfriends }).ToList();
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this is a single query using the [SQL IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
int myid = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
var friendprofile = sqlConnection.Query<profile>("Select * from profiles where friendID IN (Select friendID from friends where myid=@profile)",new { profile = myid }).ToList();
```