# mvc4 when to use sprocs versus application code to run complex queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I am new to the whole stored procedures basics; but is there a basic guideline on when to use sproc or regular ole SQL in controller ? For example I have this query which is intensive

```
     var friendprofile = sqlConnection.Query<following>("Select * from  followings where me=@profile)", new { profile = myid }).ToList();
                    List<thread> comments = new List<thread>();
             foreach(following fp in  friendprofile)
             {
                var cm=sqlConnection.Query<thread>("select * from threads where profileID=@profile",new {profile =fp.ProfileID}).FirstOrDefault();
                    comments.Add(cm);
            }
```

The query above loops around because each new user can have hundreds of new results and the code gets executed again and again someone suggested that I should create a stored procedure for that code above; would it make sense to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *could* use a stored procedure, but you don't need to.  This "someone" who suggested you use a stored procedure to solve the problem isn't correct.  You could execute a stored procedure inside a `foreach` and have the **exact** same problem.

Think of a stored procedure as a file saving a particular query.  You can execute that file once, or you could execute it infinite times.

If your goal is to reduce the number of queries being sent to the database, then you should be working towards finding a way to fetch all the data in a single query.  That could be done in a stored procedure or an ad-hoc SQL statement.

If your goal is to handle inputs more safely, then parametrized stored procedures are a great choice (especially if you're not using an ORM like Entity Framework).  There's other benefits to stored procedures as well like query plan caching, but that's a topic of its own.

Comment: It was me who suggested **considering** stored procedures, but not to _solve this problem_. It was for other reasons - OP questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480250/mvc4-take-value-from-a-tolist-query-and-apply-it-to-another-query) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458486/mvc4-how-to-extract-value-from-a-tolist-query-in-controller) was writing lengthy statements (multiple `where IN`) and having to restart app to test if syntax was correct and the correct results were being returned